# How to fix KeyError: "Column 'price' does not exist!". Although the column exists

Tags: python, pandas

it is necessary to group the observations in the table by type (mode) and for each type the average price (price), which the respondents paid.

Trying something like `df.set_index(['mode']),df.loc[:,"price"].mean()`, but this is not such result as i need. I see the result like this:

```
mode
beach 35.213412
boat 41.2341
charter 75.213412
pier 30.02384
name: price, dtype: float64

df.groupby('mode').agg({'price' :['mean']})


KeyError: "Column 'price' does not exist!"
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `df.columns`

Comment: I can't see a `price` named column here. I think you should rename the column of your dataframe and then do `df.groupby('mode')['price'].agg('mean')`

Comment: I think your df is a Series, not a DataFrame. You can try df = df.to_frame() before doing the groupby.